# Minecraft command block ops can't use

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

So my friend is trying to access a command block, he has op and gamemode 1, but when he right clicks it, nothing happens. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This question fits better on http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ as you are only trying to use a game mechanic, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a plugin is blocking the commandblock access.
Can you use the commandblock?
Add you and your friend to the op list (also check ops.json).
Try to put you and your friend into the same permission group if you have a permission plugin.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A good answer provides a solution to the posed question, not a conjecture. Clarifying questions should be posed in comments.

Answer (score 2):

In your `server.properties`, you must set `commandblocks` to true(I am not looking at one at the moment, but it is something like that). Once that is set, restart your server, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As @mttprvst13 said, make sure commandblocks is set to true in your server.properties. Plugins may also be blocking it, but probably not due to the fact that he is an operator.